# nothing happens when submitting django form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a problem with django forms, when submitting a form nothing seems to happen, even the server didn't get any response except GET request to view the form template.

here is my code for the forms.py :

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Post


class PostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post 
        fields = [
            "title",
            "content",
            "category"
        ]
```

and here is my post_form.html :

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block content %}
    <h1>form</h1>
    <form method="POST" action=".">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
    </form>
    <button type="submit">Create Post</button>
{% endblock content %}
```

and here is my handling for the form in views.py :

```
def post_create(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()

            return redirect("posts:detail", pk=post.pk)
    else :
        form = PostForm()

    context = {
        "form":form,
    }

    return render(request,"post_form.html", context)
```

Comment: remove the dot `.` in your form action. leave it blank

Comment: nothing happens

Comment: so what happens now? does it call the view nevertheless?

Comment: the problem is that submitting button is out the form tag, thank you :"D

Comment: ah ah! so you had two issues: the dot `.` and what you just said

Comment: no the dot wasn't a problem

Comment: `action={{request.path}}` or empty for the current path you also have post.save() twice also move the submit button into the form and you need to fix your view function.

Answer (score 0):

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Post


class PostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post 
        fields = ["title", "content", "category"]
```

views.py

```
def post_create(request):
    form = PostForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save()
            return redirect("posts:detail", pk=post.pk)
    return render(request,"post-form.html", {"form": form})
```

post-form.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>form</h1>
    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
         <article class="message is-danger alert-message">
             <div class="message-body">
               <p>{{ error|escape }}</p>
             </div>
         </article>
    {% endfor %}
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Create Post">
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your views:

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.commit = False
    form.save()
```

or

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save(commit=false)
```

I suggest the latter

Don't Forget Place Your Submit Button In Form Tag !